# $concat with lookup fields?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to `$concat` some fields in a MongoDB aggregation. The problem is that they are coming from  `$lookup` and apparently they can't be concatenated just like that. Here is what I'm trying:

```
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'user_id',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'user'
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            'fullname': { $concat: ['$user.lastname', ', ', '$user.firstname' ] }
        }
    }
```

This results in the following error message:

```
$concat only supports strings, not array
```

Interestingly, if I use `$concatArrays`, the message will be:

```
$concatArrays only supports arrays, not string
```

So how do I refer to a lookup field in `$concat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `user` is an array when it comes out of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) when you know you only have 1 result:

```
{ "$project": {
  "fullname": {
    "$let": {
      "vars": { "user": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$user",0] },
      "in": { "$concat": [ "$$user.lastname", ", ", "$$user.firstname" ] }
    }
  }
}}
```

Or just [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) if you have more than one:

```
  { "$unwind": "$user" },
  { "$project": {
    "fullname": { "$concat": [ "$user.lastname", ", ", "$user.firstname"' ] }
  }}
```

The output is **"always"** an array, even if it's only one result or many or even none. So you need to treat is as such with an appropriate operator.

Comment: Yay! Next question: How did I forget $unwind and fooled around with $group? Overtime all night I guess...